# Snmp configuration giving me timeout, no response

Tags: nagios, snmp, snmpd

This is definitely not a firewall issue as no firewalls are in between the src and tgt machines. I'm simply setting up snmp to be queried by a nagios server. My snmpd.conf looks like the following (I'm using net-snmp on Ubuntu 9.10):

```
com2sec nagiossrv 10.10.10.10 public
group   Nagios  v1 nagiossrv
view all included .1
access  Nagios  any     noauth  exact   all     none    none
```

When I try to walk it:

t:/etc/nagios3# snmpwalk -v1 -c public 10.10.10.10 system
Timeout: No Response from 10.10.10.10

Any idea where I went wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you get silence like that, especially from a snmpwalk or snmpget, it means that the device isn't getting your query, isn't using the snmp version you think it is, isn't configured to accept queries from your IP address, or isn't accepting your community.

Confirm that snmp is on, that the version and community is correct, that any query-based restrictions permit queries from your IP address, and that you are querying both the device and the part of the MIB you think you are.

A good basic query for most snmp v1 devices is:

```
# snmpwalk -v 1 -c public $IP .1
```

...substitute for "public" and $IP as appropriate.

Although it may not be exactly what you want, this is the snmpd.conf file that I use on Linux nodes that are being queried by cacti:

```
syslocation System Location
syscontact an.email@a.system
#      sec.name   source          community (password) 
com2sec Mybox     localhost          public 
com2sec cacti     <you ip>     public 
com2sec Outside   default            public 
#      group.name sec.model  sec.name 
group   RWGroup    v2c       Mybox 
group   ROGroup    v1        cacti 
group   ROGroup    v2c       cacti 
group   Others     v2c       Outside 
view all     included  .1        80 
view system  included  system    fe 
#              context sec.model sec.level prefix  read    write  notif 
access  ROGroup   ""      any    noauth    exact   all     none   none 
access  RWGroup   ""      v2c    noauth    exact   all     all    all 
access  Others    ""      v2c    noauth    exact   system  none   all
```

Answer (score 0):

First, did you check snmpd is running properly ?

Netstat or lsof -i udp:161 can tell you. Also have a look to logs ;)

from man snmpd.conf:

> access GROUP CONTEXT {any|v1|v2c|usm} LEVEL PREFX READ WRITE NOTIFY

You seem to be missing a field.
In my own configuration, I set **""** as third field for no particular context.

You may then try this:

> access  Nagios "" any     noauth  exact   all     none    none

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (at least in 9.10) overrides the snmpd default and only listens on localhost.  To change this edit `/etc/default/snmpd` and change from

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid 127.0.0.1'
```

to

`SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf'`

Answer (score 0):

I know its pretty old, but this is for someone like me who has been scouring the internet like hell for 3 continuous days to find the below solution:

`snmpwalk -v1 -c -t60 public 10.10.10.10 system`